# Get the exact position of div using div class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can i get the top.left, right and width of the div which has no id but only class is defined.

```
<div class="content">
</div>
```

I want to get the exact position on the screen using content class. is it possible using jqyery??

[image: Iframe]

[image: Alert code]

Comment: Do you have only one element with the *content* class?

Comment: i am building side panel ad for http://www.ninemsn.com.au/ and i want to place panel according to the content size. In the ninemsn they have a content class where all the contents are defined and i want to get the exact positioning of the div so that i can place my panels accordingly

Comment: why my question is voted negative ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getBoundingClientRect()` for `top`, `left` and `right` values. For `width` you could use `offsetWidth` if the width isn't defined anywhere.

If the `width` is defined inline you could use `element.style.width`, if it is defined in stylesheet you could use `getComputedStyle(element)`.

If you want to get the values for all elements with class `content`, you'll have to loop through them individually; else just remove the `for` loop and put `0` instead of `i`.

```
var content = document.getElementsByClassName('content');

for (i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
  console.log(content[i].getBoundingClientRect().top) //top
  console.log(content[i].getBoundingClientRect().left) //left
  console.log(content[i].getBoundingClientRect().right) //right
  console.log(content[i].offsetWidth); //width
}
```

### Example:

```js
 var content = document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0];

 console.log(content.getBoundingClientRect().top) //top
 console.log(content.getBoundingClientRect().left) //left
 console.log(content.getBoundingClientRect().right) //right
 console.log(content.offsetWidth); //width
```

```html
<div class="content"></div>
```